# Applying Proguard to Android App that Contains Multiple Library Projects

Tags: android, proguard

I have an Android app that has a main UI application project, a model library, and a UI library project.  What is the best way to setup a Proguard.cfg for multi-project structure like this?  For example does the Main UI application project need to have configurations that apply to the library projects.  Does each library project need its own config file? My app includes the model and ui projects as jar files.

Answer (score 0):

the main app config is what matters, you don't need to set the proguard config for each library project, though you should reference your libraries as Android libraries not external jars

Comment: ok. how would i reference the libraries as Android libraries in an ant build file?

Comment: I am not familiar with ant, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244248/build-android-library-project-with-ant and http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-cmdline.html#ReferencingLibraryProject it might help you